# glassfish 3.1.1 import ssl certificates

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

i`m trying to install some SSL certificates bought from godaddy.com. I found some tutorials like this one: 
http://www.denizoguz.com/2011/01/02/installing-godaddy-ssl-certificates-on-glassfish-v3-step-by-step/

My certificates were generated a year ago for apache http server, so i followed the tutorial from step 3.
 
I have imported these files in keystore.jks, i have replaced all occurrences of s1as with my certificate nickname in domain.xml, i have restarted the domain, but when i try to access something over ssl i get this in glassfish logs:

```
    [#|2011-10-04T16:02:52.972+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8181(1);|GRIZZLY0007: SSL support could not be configured!
java.io.IOException: SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:455)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.init(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:183)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.initializeSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:361)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.configureSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:239)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps$LazySSLInitializationFilter.execute(GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps.java:202)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.checkEnabledSuites(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:327)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:272)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:451)
        ... 14 more
|#]

[#|2011-10-04T16:02:52.976+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8181(1);|ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
|#]
```

any idea what i am doing wring ???

---

yes, i think that the problem resigns in the fact that my certificates are for apache http. I found this tutorial 
 http://wiki.eclipse.org/Generating_a_Private_Key_and_a_Keystore 
 that explains how to convert these certificates, but this does not seems to solve my problem eighter

---

updates,
after i followed this tutorial agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html, now i get

```
[#|2011-10-05T13:18:47.853+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8181(1);|GRIZZLY0007: SSL support could not be configured!
java.io.IOException: injection failed on com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.secSupp with class com.sun.enterprise.server.pluggable.SecuritySupport
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.init(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:188)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.initializeSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:361)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.configureSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:239)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps$LazySSLInitializationFilter.execute(GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps.java:202)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
|#]

[#|2011-10-05T13:18:47.859+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8181(1);|ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
|#]
```

---

another update
it seems that if a change the password from importkey to changeit i get this error :

```
[#|2011-10-05T13:29:17.210+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-50;|java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
java.lang.Error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.getSSLContext(SSLUtils.java:159)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.postConstruct(SSLUtils.java:125)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getBy(Habitat.java:1048)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByType(Habitat.java:1029)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getComponentInjectValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:159)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:90)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:141)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:126)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecuritySniffer.setup(SecuritySniffer.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ContainerStarter.startContainer(ContainerStarter.java:116)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:944)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:652)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:138)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:779)
        at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:68)
        at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.impl.SecuritySupportImpl.getKeyManagers(SecuritySupportImpl.java:290)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.getKeyManagers(SSLUtils.java:197)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.getSSLContext(SSLUtils.java:147)
        ... 27 more
|#]
```

Comment: Did you ensure that the keystore password has to be the same as the Glassfish master password (not admin password)?

Comment: Hi Matt, this was the exact problem, as soon as i changed the master password to importkey everything works as expected. This solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Good to hear. So I will add an answer that you can accept.

Comment: I just posted an answer related to this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345109/glassfish-protocolchain-exception/10803851#10803851

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ensure that the keystore password matches the Glassfish master password (which is *not* the admin password).

Here is [a tutorial how to change the master password](https://blogs.oracle.com/bhaktimehta/entry/change_master_password_command_in) for GF 3.1

Comment: This is a critical pointer; more importantly; the keypass of the target key alias should be same as the master password.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have either some setup issues or a known bug. Check this [post](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/oracle-glassfish-31) out.

From the thread:

"2. This is a set up issue. They cannot find the corresponding certificates.
Can you double check the *.jks file? Note that the default keystore
password is changeit."