# Glassfish ProtocolChain exception

Tags: exception, https, glassfish

I'm trying to add to my glassfish server the support for http, so I looked on internet and I found this tutorial :
http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/

I tried to add the trusted certificates in both cacerts.jks and server.keystore, I changed my master password to match the one from the keystores, I've tried almost each options on the glassfish admin interface without success. Maybe you will be able to help

Here are my logs:

```
[#|2011-12-01T17:32:08.281+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0007: SSL support could not be configured!
java.io.IOException: SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:455)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.init(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:183)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.initializeSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:361)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.configureSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:239)
        at com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps$LazySSLInitializationFilter.execute(GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps.java:202)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.checkEnabledSuites(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:310)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:255)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:451)
        ... 14 more
|#]

[#|2011-12-01T17:32:08.322+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2011-12-01T17:32:08.322+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the network listener again, in [Configurations] > [server-config] > [Network config] > [Network listeners] choose the corresponding listener, e.g. the admin listener or http-listener-2. Open the tab [SSL], scroll down and check which cipher suites are selected to be used in the lists on the right side. For testing purposes try to add all available ciphers.

After this re-check in the [General] tab that you have chosen the certificate nickname which you used as alias when importing the certificate with keytool.

Save changes and definitely restart the domain (restart Glassfish server).

Comment: I already tried to activate all ciphers. The nickname is the same as the alias i gave to the certificates and the alias I use for:

keytool -list -v -alias MYALIAS -keystore server.keystore

and truststore:

cacerts.jks

in which I also added the certifcates of my cert chain.

for the keystore i put : server.keystore

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, glassfish was not syncing the keystore.jks and cacerts.jks from the domain directory to the instance directory.

I copied both files from *glassfish/domains/domain_name/config* to *nodes/node_name/instance_name/config*

After restarting everything worked just fine!